# scodec ignore last value in codec conversion between hlist and case class

Tags: scala, scodec

I'm just starting out with typelevel's "scodec" library: https://github.com/scodec/scodec

I've found that I've been using the following function a lot:

```
/**
 * When called on a `Codec[L]` for some `L <: HList`, returns a new codec that encodes/decodes
 * `B :: L` but only returns `L`.  HList equivalent of `~>`.
 * @group hlist
 */
def :~>:[B](codec: Codec[B])(implicit ev: Unit =:= B): Codec[L] = codec.dropLeft(self)
```

This is useful if I have a case class where I don't want to use every value of the spec:

```
case class Example(value1: Int, value3)
implicit val exampleCodec: Codec[Example] = (
("value1" | uint8) :: 
("value2" | uint8) :~>: // decode/encode, but dont pass this in when converting from hlist to case class
("value3" | uint8)
).as[Example]
```

This works well if the value I want to ignore isn't the last one in the hlist.  Would anyone know how to change the codec, if instead I wanted my case class to be:

case class Example(value1: Int, value2: Int)   // ignore value3

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `<~`, so instead of this:

```
implicit val exampleCodec: Codec[Example] = (
  ("value1" | uint8) :: 
  ("value2" | uint8).unit(0) :~>:
  ("value3" | uint8)
).as[Example]
```

You'd write this:

```
implicit val exampleCodec: Codec[Example] = (
  ("value1" | uint8) :: 
  ("value3" | uint8) <~
  ("value2" | uint8).unit(0)
).as[Example]
```

Note that you explicitly have to make the codec a `Codec[Unit]`—I'm using `.unit(0)` here for the sake of example.

Comment: Ah nice! Just look for the dropRight I suppose - thanks.

Comment: In addition to the above technique, you can leave the Unit values in the HList and remove them just before binding to the case class. That is, use :: throughout and then use .dropUnits.as[Example].